# Grails returns server error after creating domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am a newbie to Grails and I am stuck with the GORM part. I tried to follow tutorial on this site http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-introduction-to-gorm about GORM and the first thing to do is create a domain class. However, after following the instructions there, I always received the error showed below.

My controller for inserting record

```
package nba

class PlayerController {

def index() { 

    //render "It's game time! NBA Game time"
    Player p = new Player()
    p.fname = "Lebron"
    p.lname = "James"
    p.position = "Small Forward"
    p.age = 30

  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

[image]. What is the problem with this. What am I lacking? Please help.

```
---
grails:
profile: web
codegen:
    defaultPackage: myapp
info:
app:
    name: '@info.app.name@'
    version: '@info.app.version@'
    grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
groovy:
    template:
        check-template-location: false

---
grails:
mime:
    disable:
        accept:
            header:
                userAgents:
                    - Gecko
                    - WebKit
                    - Presto
                    - Trident
    types:
        all: '*/*'
        atom: application/atom+xml
        css: text/css
        csv: text/csv
        form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        html:
          - text/html
          - application/xhtml+xml
        js: text/javascript
        json:
          - application/json
          - text/json
        multipartForm: multipart/form-data
        pdf: application/pdf
        rss: application/rss+xml
        text: text/plain
        hal:
          - application/hal+json
          - application/hal+xml
        xml:
          - text/xml
          - application/xml
urlmapping:
    cache:
        maxsize: 1000
controllers:
    defaultScope: singleton
converters:
    encoding: UTF-8
views:
    default:
        codec: html
    gsp:
        encoding: UTF-8
        htmlcodec: xml
        codecs:
            expression: html
            scriptlets: html
            taglib: none
            staticparts: none
---
hibernate:
cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: true
    use_query_cache: false
    region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

endpoints:
jmx:
    unique-names: true

dataSource:
pooled: true
jmxExport: true
driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


environments:
development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: create-drop
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/grails_db
        username: root
        password:
test:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/grails_db
production:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/grails_db
        properties:
            jmxEnabled: true
            initialSize: 5
            maxActive: 50
            minIdle: 5
            maxIdle: 25
            maxWait: 10000
            maxAge: 600000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
            validationQuery: SELECT 1
            validationQueryTimeout: 3
            validationInterval: 15000
            testOnBorrow: true
            testWhileIdle: true
            testOnReturn: false
            jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
            defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Comment: You forget to post your code. The error is clear though you are getting NullPointerException

Comment: Please take a look. Just a very simple code

Comment: please dont use image. Also post the code that use the domain object.

Comment: p.save() ? is missing then you are not rendering anything, it is giving you some obsecure message about your controller not matching boolean of domain class. I suspect if you add after p.save() a new line saying render 'Hey I forgot to render something to screen' and try again you will get the idea

Comment: Thanks. Is that all I need? This is how I got the error, when I created a domain class player and then put the field names (fname, lname, position, age), it was successful, the table player is created in the database together with field names but when I restarted running the server, the table was deleted automatically and the running back the server returns error. What is the problem with that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't see your comment:

Firstly to expand on my comment above and explain grails controller behaviour better. I will stick with render you have other choices.

When declaring an action in your controller:

so lets say we have

```
class TestController {
    def hello() { }
}
```

You may or may not have a domainClass bound to this example TestController, if you did the domain class would be {package}/Test.groovy {matching the naming construct of controller}.

In this example we have no domain controller and above action will show something as long as you create a folder under views called

```
test/hello.gsp
```

So in that test folder you create hello.gsp and put in there some html..

If you didn't have

```
test/hello.gsp
```

Then in your controller you would have to define what to render.

```
class TestController {
        def hello() { 
          // render 'some text'
          //render template: '/path/to/template', model: [params:params]
          render view: '/path/to/gsp', model: [params:params]
        }
    }
```

You then state:

> This is how I got the error, when I created a domain class player and
> then put the field names (fname, lname, position, age), it was
> successful, the table player is created in the database together with
> field names but when I restarted running the server, the table was
> deleted automatically and the running back the server returns error.
> What is the problem with that?

Firstly you need to then ask yourself, did you configure/install some DB in order to see it working initially?

Grails provides you with an inbuilt DB that resides in your memory as part of its default app creation.In short a fresh DB is triggered on each run app.

E2A

Pay attention to dbCreate line:

> create-drop : Creates tables on application startup and drops then when shutdown
>
> create : Creates all tables at app start up
>
> update : Updates existing tables (will not attempt to create any. that's down to you)

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/conf.html

> In development mode dbCreate is by default set to "create-drop", but
> at some point in development (and certainly once you go to production)
> you'll need to stop dropping and re-creating the database every time
> you start up your server.

Comment: Why is it that the table is deleted everytime I terminate my server in the terminal? Is that how grails really works or do I have something to configure?

Comment: When you terminate a grails app. If your data source points to internal db. Meaning if you haven't configured your own db then data is lost. Look at installing mysql and then how to configure grails app to work with mysql

Comment: I already configure my database using mysql. Please take a look above. I pasted my database configuration.